# Dynamically loading content into TinyMce through jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I'm trying to load content from records in my database, the database does indeed return the correct values; the problem is populating TinyMce with said values.

The HTML:

```
        <textarea cols="20" class="tiny modal-body-content">
        </textarea>
```

The Ajax (jQuery)

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/WebServices/masterData.asmx/ShowBio',
            data: t,
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError,
            timeout: 15000
        });

        function OnSuccess(data, status) {
            if (data.d != "false") {
                tinymce.init({
                    selector: "tiny",
                    setup: function (editor) {
                        editor.on('init', function () {
                            editor.setContent(data.d);
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
```

I also tried populating the HTML into the ID TinyMce generates using:

```
$(".mce-edit-area").html(data.d);
```

Although this does put the HTML into the TinyMce editor, it's not editable, and quite clearly a massive bodge.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
        function OnSuccess(data, status) {
            if (data.d != "false") {
                $(".tiny").html(data.d);
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data.d);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

this will add the content (tag/element/text or whatever .. ) exactly in the current mouse position :

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand(
 'mceInsertContent',
  false, 
  '<span style="text-decoration : underline">an Appended Content !</span>');
```

while this will inject directly the content on the TinyMce editor (wiping of the previous content)

```
 tinymce.activeEditor.setContent("<p>I will replace the original content</p>", {
                            format: 'raw'
                        });
```

Here is a quick example with AJax :

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Documents/ajaxGetDocumentById/2',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function (document) {
                    $("#form-edit").attr(
                        'action',
                        '/Documents/EditExistingDocument/2'
                    );
                    $("#input-document-title").val(document.title);
                    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(document.CustomHtmlContent, {
                        format: 'raw'
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Erreur de requéte Ajax ....');
                }
            });
```